Muted sound after Linux boot
I am faced with a sound output problem. After I installed Linux (in my case, Kali or Mint), sound is muted. When I run alsamixer, it shows 0% every time system is booted. Could you help me to fix the problem? After system boot I have to run alsamixer and set volume levels every time, in spite of I have already executed alsactl store command.
So, my current system settings are listed below.
pactl info:
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 70
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: leonx300
Host Name: leonx300-1001pxd
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 1.0.6)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
Cookie: dcb9:2b3d

pactl list sinks:
Sink #51
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
    Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: PipeWire
    Sample Specification: s32le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 4294967295
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 47320 /  72% / -8.49 dB,   front-right: 46664 /  71% / -8.85 dB
            balance -0.01
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0269,10438437,00100100"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        alsa.id = "Intel"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel at 0xf7cf8000 irq 25"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC269VB"
        alsa.name = "ALC269VB Analog"
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HDA Intel at 0xf7cf8000 irq 25"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HDA Intel"
        api.alsa.path = "front:0"
        api.alsa.pcm.card = "0"
        api.alsa.pcm.stream = "playback"
        audio.channels = "2"
        audio.position = "FL,FR"
        card.profile.device = "3"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.id = "47"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.routes = "2"
        factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.sink"
        media.class = "Audio/Sink"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo"
        node.nick = "ALC269VB Analog"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:0:front:0:playback"
        priority.driver = "1009"
        priority.session = "1009"
        factory.id = "18"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        client.id = "46"
        node.driver = "true"
        factory.mode = "merge"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        object.id = "51"
        object.serial = "51"
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "0"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio0"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1.Priority = "-20"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0"
        device.nick = "HDA Intel"
        device.plugged.usec = "168507303"
        device.product.id = "0x27d8"
        device.product.name = "NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (Eee PC 1015PX)"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.vendor.id = "0x8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.string = "0"
    Ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (type: Speaker, priority: 10000, availability group: Legacy 3, availability unknown)
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, availability group: Legacy 2, not available)
    Active Port: analog-output-speaker
    Formats:
        pcm

/proc/asound/cards content:
 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xf7cf8000 irq 25

/proc/asound/pcm content:
00-00: ALC269VB Analog : ALC269VB Analog : playback 1 : capture 1

I tried to create sound configuraton file ~/.asoundrc like
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}

But it had no effect. Thus, I never understood how to permanently save changes of volume level configuration in my system. Thank you in advance for your answers!
